# What is the best way to organise a log parser function?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

I've been writing a log parser to get some information out of some logs and then use it elsewhere. The idea is to run it over a series of log files and store the useful information in a database for use in the future. The language I'm using is python(3.8)

The types of information extracted from the logs are json-type strings, which I store in dictionaries, normal alphanumeric strings, timestamps(which we convert to datetime objects), integers and floats - sometimes as values in dictionary-type format.

I've made a parse_logs(filepath) method that takes a filepath and returns a list of dictionaries with all the messages within them. A message can consist of multiple of the above types, and in order to parse those logs I've written a number of methods to isolate message from the log lines into a list of strings and then manipulate those lists of lines that make up a message to extract various kinds of information.

This has resulted in a main `parse_logs(filepath: str) -> list` function with multiple helper functions (like `extract_datetime_from_header(header_line: str) -> datetime`  , `extract_message(messages: list) -> list` and `process_message(message: list) -> dict`  that each does a specific thing, but are not useful to any other part of the project I'm working on as they are very specific to aid this function.
The only additional thing I wish to do (right now, at least) is take those messages and save their information in a database.

-So, there are 2 main ways that I'm thinking of organising my code: One is making a LogParser class and it will have a path to the log and a message list as attributes, and all of the functions as class methods. (In that case what should the indentation level of the helper classes be? should they be their own methods or should they just be functions defined inside the method they are supposed to enable? ).
The other is just having a base function(and nesting all helper functions inside it, as I assume that I wouldn't want them imported as standalone functions) and just run that method with only the path as an argument, and it will return the message list to a caller function that will take the list, parse it and move each message in it's place in the database.
-Another thing that I'm considering is whether to use dataclasses instead of dictionaries for the data. The speed difference won't matter much since it's a script that's gonna run just a few times a day as a cronjob and it won't matter that much if it takes 5 seconds or 20 to run(unless the difference is way more, I've only tested it on log examples of half a MB instead of 4-6 GB that are the expected ones)
My final concern is keeping the message objects in-memory and feeding them directly to the database writer. I've done a bit of testing and estimating and I expect that 150MB seems like a reasonable ceiling for a worst-case scenario (that is a log full of only useful data that's a 40% larger than the current largest log that we have - so even if we scale to 3times that amount, I think that a 16gb RAM machine should be able to handle that without any trouble).

So, with all these said, I'd like to ask for best practices on how to handle organising the code, namely:

1. Is the class/oop way a better practice than just writing functions that do the work? Is it more readable/maintainable?
2. Should I use dataclasses or stick to dictionaries? What are the advantages/disadvantages of both? Which is better maintainable and which is more efficient?
3. If I care about handling data from the database and not from these objects(dicts or data classes), which is the more efficient way to go?
4. Is it alright to keep the message objects in-memory until the database transaction is complete or should I handle it in a different manner? I've thought of either doing a single transaction after I finish parsing a single log (but I was told that it could lead to both bad scalability since the temporary list of messages would keep increasing in-memory up to the point where they'd be used in the db transaction - and that a single large transaction could also be in turn slow) or of writing every message as it's parsed(as a dictionary object) in a file in disc and then parse that intermediary(is that the correct word? ) file to the function that will handle the db transactions and do them in batches (I was told that's not a good practice either), or write directly to the db while parsing messages (either after every message or in small batches so that the total message list doesn't get to grow too large). I've even thought of going a producer/consumer route and keep a shared variable that the producer(log parser) will append to while the consumer(database writer) will consume, both until the log is fully parsed. But this route is not something that I've done before (except for a few times for interview questions, which was rather simplistic and it felt hard to debug or maintain so I don't feel that confident in doing right now). What are the best practices regarding the above?

Thank you very much for your time! I know it's a bit of a lot that I've asked, but I did feel like writing down all of the thoughts that I had and read some people's opinions on them. Till then I'm gonna try to do an implementation for all of the above ideas (except perhaps the producer/consumer) and see which feels more maintainable, human readable and intuitively correct to me.

Comment: In FP a simple parser is a function that takes a string and returns a pair tuple containing either the reduced string and a tree-like parser result or the original string and an error message. This is the fundamental buildling block from where you can build simple parsers like `success`, `fail`, `try` or `satisfy`. Since parsers are just higher order functions you can compose them to create even more complex parsers.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Iven, it seems that I've never understood what functional programming is. If I understand what you're saying then it's about using recursive functions, and not just organizing your functions in a specific way. 
I've edited the functional tag out, then, as I'm not looking for a functional solution at this time, although it did pique my interest and I'll find some way to study it when I have some free time! 
I'd appreciate any further input on the original questions, though!
Cheers!

Comment: The "functional" in functional programming doesn't just refer to using functions (everything uses functions), but *pure* functions in the mathematical sense: no side effects, the return value is determined solely by the argument(s), etc. The parser described above is functional because it doesn't use any external state to keep track of which part of the input has been parsed, but instead every function passes what it *didn't* parse on to the next function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Is the class/oop way a better practice than just writing functions that do the work? Is it more readable/maintainable?

I don't think there's necessarily a best approach. I've seen the following work equally well:

1. OOP: You'd have a `Parser` class which uses instance variables to share the parsing state. The parser can be made thread-safe, or not.
2. Closures: You'd use nested functions to create closures over the input & parsing state.
3. Functional: You'd pass the input & parsing state to functions which yields back the parsing state (e.g. AST + updated cursor index).

> 2. Should I use dataclasses or stick to dictionaries? What are the advantages/disadvantages of both? Which is better maintainable and which is more efficient?

ASTs are usually represented in 2 ways ([homogenous vs heterogenous](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/199534/homogeneous-vs-heterogeneous-ast-representation)):

1. Homogeneous: you'd have a single `ASTNode { type, children }` class to represent all the node types.
2. Heterogenous: you'd have a concrete node class per type.

Your approach is kinda a mix of both, because as a key/value store, dictionaries can be a little more expressive for pointing to other nodes than list indexes, but all nodes are still represented with the same underlying type. I usually favor #2 with custom classes as those are self-documenting the structure of the tree, although in a dynamically typed language there's probably less benefits.

As to performance, IDK Python well enough, but quick Googling seems to point out that dictionaries are most performant overall.

> 3. If I care about handling data from the database and not from these objects(dicts or data classes), which is the more efficient way to go?

If in-memory AST consumers are uninteresting and you won't have much AST processing operations then I guess it's a bit less important to invest much time & effort into the AST representation, although if you only have a few kind of nodes making it explicit from the start shouldn't be a huge effort.

> 4. Is it alright to keep the message objects in-memory until the database transaction is complete...

Honestly when you are talking runtime & memory optimizations it really depends. I'd say **avoid getting trapped into premature optimization**. How big those logs are likely to be? Would memory overflows be likely? Is the operation so time-consuming that crashing and having to start over unacceptable?

These are all questions that will help you determine which is the most appropriate approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has been very enlightening! 
I don't think that I'm going to need ASTs as the cases are both simpler but also erratic(there's no real pattern to follow, I have to extract some data from each line based on a different identifier).
Your comment on not getting trapped on premature optimisation though was the most important one. I went with making a parser class that holds state and a parser method, and some static helper methods and it seems to both work nicely and is relatively well-structured and easy to read, which is something that I'm happy with!
Thanks again! :)

Comment: Yeah I realized after posting that my answer was geared towards parsing in general, but perhaps made more sense for DSLs than log entries. One core distinction is that it's far easier to write a lazy parser for log entries than a DSL because you know you can parse up to the next record and return.